# Showing a few figures without stopping calculations in matplotlib

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib

Hi I would like to show a few figures in matplotlib without stopping calculations. I would like the figure to show up right after the calculations that concern it are finished for example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as py

x=np.linspace(0,50,51)
y=x
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1)
cs = axs.plot(x, y)
```

now i want to show the plot without blocking the possibility to make some other calculations

```
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(5)
```

I create the second plot

```
y1=2*x
fig1, axs1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
cs1 = axs1.plot(x, y1)

plt.show()
```

This works however the first freezes (after 5 secound pause which I added) until I call plt.show() at the end. It is crucial that the first figure shows and works, then after calculations another figure is added to it.

Comment: I found some old answer to this topic at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2134/ comment by efiring. Basically he says that when there are computations performed the figures will freeze and there's nothing to be done about it. One must stop computations to work with the plot. Maybe something has changed since then?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want.  I did this in an IPython Notebook.

```
from IPython import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def stream_plot(iterable, plotlife=10.):

        for I in iterable:
            display.clear_output(wait=True)
            output = do_calculations_on_i(I)
            plt.plot(output)
            display.display(plt.gca());
            time.sleep(plotlife); #how long to show the plot for
```

the wait=True will wait to clear the old plot until it has something new to plot, or any other output is printed.

I put the sleep in there so I can observe each plot before it is wiped away.  This was useful for having to observe distributions for several entities.  You may or may not need it for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does this code do calculations for some I and stops calculations to show the plot for 10 secounds for other?

Comment: @Revist, yes.  If your calculations take long enough, you would not need to sleep (pause) the loop operation.
I missed your point of wanting to add the figure to the previous one. Can you provide a little bit more context as to your task?  Without knowing, You could just put the output into some list, and replot at each iteration from that list.